# after_update not triggering when counter cache is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 6.1.4.1, I am using a counter cache column on one of my models, and I have a `after_update` filter that broadcasts the object using ActionCable. When I add a record to the associated model records that the counter cache is for, the counter gets updated correctly, but nothing is broadcasted. I have verified that other updates made directly to the object result in a broadcast happening, so I know that part is working. Is there a way to trigger `after_update` or some other callback when my counter cache column is updated?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I moved the broadcast method from the model `after_update` to its association's `after_create` and `after_destroy` since those are the two times when the counter cache column would get updated anyway. Not quite as clean, but it works.